# I try to add OOTB workflow to library, error: The form cannot be rendered. This may be due to a misconfiguration of

Tags: workflow

I am using SharePoint 2013 onpremise. I have a document library. I tried to add the OOTB workflow "Approval - SharePoint 2010".

I can see the first page where I can select the OOTB workflow and set title. I click on next and get this error below:

> The form cannot be rendered. This may be due to a misconfiguration of
>   the Microsoft SharePoint Server State Service. For more information,
>   contact your server administrator

In ULS logs I found these errors:

1. `StateServiceApplicationProxy.GetDefaultProxy()` called but could not find a proxy to return.
2. The FormServer is not configured properly: The StateService cannot issue a new session, either because no StateServiceApplicationProxy is bound to the current webapp, or because no online and unpaused databases could be found.
3. Microsoft SharePoint State Service is not configured correctly and cannot respond to requests. InfoPath Forms Services relies on Microsoft SharePoint State Service to function correctly. Check the SharePoint Maintenance Engine rules in SharePoint Central Administration for issues with Microsoft SharePoint State Service configuration.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Creating state service service application by powershell fix this issue:

```
$serviceApp = New-SPStateServiceApplication -Name “State Service Application”
New-SPStateServiceDatabase -Name “SharePoint_Service_State” -ServiceApplication $serviceApp
New-SPStateServiceApplicationProxy -Name “State Service Application Proxy” -ServiceApplication $serviceApp -DefaultProxyGroup
```